# Is the Risch algorithm implemented in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The command of Mathematica 12.3.1

```
Integrate[(4 x - 1)/Sqrt[x^4 - 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1],x]//ToRadicals
```

> `(2 (-4 I - Sqrt[1 - 4 I] - Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I]) (1/2 ((-1 - 2 I) + Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) +  x)^2 \[Sqrt]((Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I] (-4 I - Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) ((1 + 2 I) +  Sqrt[1 + 4 I] - 2 x) ((-1 + 2 I) + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] +  2 x))/((4 I + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + Sqrt[1 + 4 I])^2 ((-1 - 2 I) + Sqrt[1 + 4 I] + 2 x)^2)) Sqrt[-(((4 I + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] -  Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) ((1 - 2 I) + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] - 2 x))/( Sqrt[1 -  4 I] ((-1 - 2 I) + Sqrt[1 + 4 I] +  2 x)))] (((-1 - 4 I) + 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) EllipticF[ ArcSin[Sqrt[ 2] \[Sqrt]((Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I] ((-1 + 2 I) + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + 2 x))/((4 I +  Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) ((-1 - 2 I) + Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I] + 2 x)))], 1/2 + 9/(2 Sqrt[17])] +  2 (4 I + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] - Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) EllipticPi[( 4 I + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + Sqrt[1 + 4 I])/(2 Sqrt[1 + 4 I]),  ArcSin[Sqrt[ 2] \[Sqrt]((Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I] ((-1 + 2 I) + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + 2 x))/((4 I +  Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) ((-1 - 2 I) + Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I] + 2 x)))], 1/2 + 9/(2 Sqrt[17])]))/(Sqrt[ 1 + 4 I] (-4 I - Sqrt[1 - 4 I] + Sqrt[1 + 4 I]) Sqrt[ 1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 - 2 x^3 + x^4])`

finds the integral in terms of elliptic integrals, whereas there is an elementary antiderivative

```
Simplify[D[Log[x^4 - 3*x^3 + 5*x^2 -  2*x + (x^2 - 2*x + 2)*Sqrt[x^4 - 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1]], x] - 
(4 x - 1)/Sqrt[x^4 - 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1]]
```

> `0`

Rubi fails with it.

So the question arises: is  [the Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) implemented in Mathematica?

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html

Comment: Risch is not implemented in full generality for handling of algebraics. That is to say, the extensions of Trager and Bronstein are not done is a general way.

Comment: By the way, this example will improve in the next release: `In[5]:= i1 = (4 x - 1)/Sqrt[x^4 - 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1];                       

In[6]:= InputForm[i2 = Integrate[i1,x]]                                           

Out[6]//InputForm= 
-Log[-2*x + 5*x^2 - 3*x^3 + x^4 + (-2 + 2*x - x^2)*
    Sqrt[1 + 2*x + 3*x^2 - 2*x^3 + x^4]]

In[7]:= Together[D[i2,x] - i1]                                                    

Out[7]= 0`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am sure it has parts of it implemented. But as far as I know, there is no CAS which has full implementation of all Risch algorithm parts.

FriCAS is known to have a more complete implementation. To what extent, I do not know.

```
                       FriCAS Computer Algebra System 
                            Version: FriCAS 1.3.7
                 Timestamp: Wed Jun 30 10:10:46 PM CDT 2021

(1) -> integrate((4*x - 1)/sqrt(x^4 - 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1),x)


                      +--------------------------+
         2            | 4      3      2               4      3      2
   log((x  - 2 x + 2)\|x  - 2 x  + 3 x  + 2 x + 1  + x  - 3 x  + 5 x  - 2 x)
```

Maple 2021 has now an option to specify Risch algorithm.  But it failed on the above.

In Mathematica, you can use `IntegrateAlgebraic` to get the simpler result instead of `Integrate`

```
IntegrateAlgebraic[(4 x - 1)/Sqrt[x^4 - 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1], x]

 -Log[-2 x+5 x^2-3 x^3+x^4+(-2+2 x-x^2) Sqrt[1+2 x+3 x^2-2 x^3+x^4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

as far as I know `IntegrateAlgebraic` will become part of `Integrate` in version 13 according to this [blog](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/08/18/new-methods-for-computing-algebraic-integrals/) about it by the author Sam Blake.  But we will know for sure when version 13 is released.

`IntegrateAlgebraic` is at https://github.com/stblake/algebraic_integration  and also as a resource function (but might not be the exact version as the one at github).  https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntegrateAlgebraic/

Comment: Thanks @Nasser! This example can be computed with my package, IntegrateAlgebraic, which is now part of Integrate:

In[352]:= Integrate[(4 x - 1)/Sqrt[x^4 - 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1], x]

Out[352]= -Log[-2 x + 5 x^2 - 3 x^3 + x^4 + (-2 + 2 x - x^2) Sqrt[1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 - 2 x^3 + x^4]]